# Push object into an array of objects nested within an array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to push the values "label" and "link" into an object within "data" where the target is the object with an id that is equal to the "parent" value of another object. These values should be pushed into the "children" property of the matching target object. This does not appear to be working. Any pointers?

```
var data = [
  {
    "id": 0,
    "label": "example page0",
    "link": "/apx/...",
    "icon": "..",
    "parent": null
    "children": null
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "label": "example page1",
    "link": "/apx/...",
    "icon": "notes",
    "parent": null
    "children": null
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "label": "example page2",
    "link": "/apx/....",
    "icon": "...",
    "parent": null
    "children": null
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "label": "example subpage3",
    "link": "/apx/....",
    "icon": "...",
    "parent": 2
    "children": null
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "label": "example subpage4",
    "link": "/apx/....",
    "icon": "...",
    "parent": 2
    "children": null
  }]

for (let entry of data) {
  if (entry.parent > 0) {
  var index = data.findIndex(x => x.id == entry.parent);
  data[index].children.push({ label: entry.label, link: entry.link })
  }
  }
```

Expected output:

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "label": "example page0",
    "link": "/apx/...",
    "icon": "..",
    "parent": null
    "children": null
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "label": "example page1",
    "link": "/apx/...",
    "icon": "notes",
    "parent": null
    "children": null
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "label": "example page2",
    "link": "/apx/....",
    "icon": "...",
    "parent": null
    "children": [ 
    { "label": "example subpage3", "link": "/apx/...." },
    { "label": "example subpage4", "link": "/apx/...." }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement it by using `Array.prototype.reduce`. The `reduce` will iterate over the `data` array and find elements having the `parent` property which are not `null` and find its parent from the `data` array by searching with the `id` property.

Now you need to check whether the `children` property is existing or not, if not you need to create a new array object and assign to the `children` property, else just append to existing `children` array:

```js
const data = [{"id":0,"label":"example page0","link":"/apx/...","icon":"..","parent":null,"children":null},{"id":1,"label":"example page1","link":"/apx/...","icon":"notes","parent":null,"children":null},{"id":2,"label":"example page2","link":"/apx/....","icon":"...","parent":null,"children":null},{"id":3,"label":"example subpage3","link":"/apx/....","icon":"...","parent":2,"children":null},{"id":4,"label":"example subpage4","link":"/apx/....","icon":"...","parent":2,"children":null}]

const res = data.reduce((acc, entry, idx, data) => {
  if (entry.parent > 0) {
    const matchingParent = data.find(e => e.id === entry.parent);
    if (matchingParent) {
      const child = {
        label: entry.label,
        link: entry.link
      };
      if (matchingParent.children) {
        matchingParent.children.push(child)
      } else {
        matchingParent.children = [child];
      }
    }
  } else {
    acc.push(entry);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(res);
```

You can also do it using a `for..of` loop also:

```js
const data = [{"id":0,"label":"example page0","link":"/apx/...","icon":"..","parent":null,"children":null},{"id":1,"label":"example page1","link":"/apx/...","icon":"notes","parent":null,"children":null},{"id":2,"label":"example page2","link":"/apx/....","icon":"...","parent":null,"children":null},{"id":3,"label":"example subpage3","link":"/apx/....","icon":"...","parent":2,"children":null},{"id":4,"label":"example subpage4","link":"/apx/....","icon":"...","parent":2,"children":null}];

const acc = [];
for (let entry of data) {
  if (entry.parent > 0) {
    const matchingParent = data.find(e => e.id === entry.parent);
    if (matchingParent) {
      const child = {
        label: entry.label,
        link: entry.link
      };
      if (matchingParent.children) {
        matchingParent.children.push(child)
      } else {
        matchingParent.children = [child];
      }
    }
  } else {
    acc.push(entry);
  }
}
console.log(acc);
```

This is when processing needs to happen in-place. In that case we find elements with non-null `parents` we can add those as `children` to the `parent` element and remove those from the `data` array using `splice`.

Iterating backwards as the `splice` will change the `length` property of the data array:

```js
const data = [{"id":0,"label":"example page0","link":"/apx/...","icon":"..","parent":null,"children":null},{"id":1,"label":"example page1","link":"/apx/...","icon":"notes","parent":null,"children":null},{"id":2,"label":"example page2","link":"/apx/....","icon":"...","parent":null,"children":null},{"id":3,"label":"example subpage3","link":"/apx/....","icon":"...","parent":2,"children":null},{"id":4,"label":"example subpage4","link":"/apx/....","icon":"...","parent":2,"children":null}];


for (let i = data.length - 1; i>= 0; i--) {
  const entry = data[i];
  if (entry.parent > 0) {
    const matchingParent = data.find(e => e.id === entry.parent);
    if (matchingParent) {
      const child = {
        label: entry.label,
        link: entry.link
      };
      if (matchingParent.children) {
        matchingParent.children.push(child)
      } else {
        matchingParent.children = [child];
      }
      data.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
}
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Is there a way to do this with out creating a array but modifying the 'data' array?

Comment: @mister.cake better to reassign the new array to the old variable `data` than modify the source array in-place. But if that is really required I have updated the answer.